# Execute another containers command in another container docker

Tags: docker, go, redis, docker-compose

I have 2 containers: a Redis container and a container for a Golang application. My Golang application is trying to perform Redis Mass Insertion (https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) by executing a bash script with the command `cat ${FILE}| redis-cli --pipe -h ${HOST}`.

However, `redis-cli` is not found within the PATH system variable and it is not a built-in shell command in the Golang application service.

Hence, I get an `exit status 127`, which means the given command in not found. I would like to know how I would be able to execute the bash script without `redis-cli` command in the Golang application service.

Comment: Need more info.  Does the command need to be run from within the container? or will you run the command from the docker host server?  Are the two containers on the same host server?

Comment: Yes, the command redis-cli needs to be run from within the same container

Comment: Yes, the two containers are on the same host server (my localhost)

Comment: Can the command be run from the host server instead of from within the golang app container?

Comment: This could definitely be done, but I would like to know if the latter would be possible.

Comment: I have some test cases which need to be run from within the golang app container. This depends on the redis-cli command and needs to be executed after the mass insertion is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run the command from within the application container only if you rebuild your go application image and install the redis cli tools.
Example using an ubuntu based image (add this to your Dockerfile):
`RUN apt update; apt -y install redis-tools`
If you are using docker compose, you can talk to your redis server using the name specified in your docker compose file.

`cat ${FILE}| redis-cli --pipe -h redis-server`

Assuming you name your redis container as shown in this sample

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: xxx
[...]
```

Alternatively, if you want to run the command from the host server, you'll have to make sure you are forwarding the redis port from the redis container, then you can use:

```
docker exec {containerId} 'cat {FILE}' | redis-cli --pipe -h localhost:{REDIS_CONTAINER_PORT}`
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to install redis on an alpine image. I am using `golang:1.10.1-alpine3.7`. I tried `RUN apk add --no-cache redis`, but i still get redis-cli command not found

Answer (score 1):

When you build your application docker image make sure you have install redis client and bash, 
Depending on base image you may use apk add bash, or apt-get install -y bash.  For instance if you are using alpine base image your Docker file might look like:

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.10.1-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates bash redis
RUN apk add --update tzdata curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
ADD myapp /
CMD ["myapp"]
```

Comment: Hey! I think `RUN apk add -y redis-tools` gives `apk: unrecognized option: y`

Comment: Sorry but that fails too with 
`ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  redis-tools (missing):
    required by: world[redis-tools]`

Comment: I am using the image `golang:1.10.1-alpine3.7`.

Comment: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=redis&branch=v3.7&repo=main&arch=x86_64  looks like alpine has packaged called redis,